# How to send the result of a pipline into a switch statement?

Tags: rescript

I want to send the result of a pipeline into a switch statement

```ml
let onWithOptions = (~key: string, eventName, options: options, decoder) =>
  onCB(eventName, key, event => {
    
  ...
    event |> Tea_json.Decoder.decodeEvent(decoder) |> 
      switch x {
      | Ok(a) => Some(a)
      | Error(_) => None
      }

  })
```

I have tried to do it this way but it didn't work x is not recognizable in the switch statement

```ml
let onWithOptions = (~key: string, eventName, options: options, decoder) =>
  onCB(eventName, key, event => {
    
  ...
    let x = event |> Tea_json.Decoder.decodeEvent(decoder) |> 
      switch x {
      | Ok(a) => Some(a)
      | Error(_) => None
      }

  })
```

Any idea on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an anonymous function to pass it into:

```ml
    let x = event |> Tea_json.Decoder.decodeEvent(decoder) |> (x =>
      switch x {
      | Ok(a) => Some(a)
      | Error(_) => None
      })
```

This is the closest equivalent in Rescript to the `function` shot-hand in OCaml. But in this scenario is really just a convoluted way of giving the value a name:

```ml
    let x = event |> Tea_json.Decoder.decodeEvent(decoder)
    let x =
      switch x {
      | Ok(a) => Some(a)
      | Error(_) => None
      }
```